# Set font for whole file without losing other formatting

Tags: inkscape, text, svg

I want to  change the font family globally in all text
objects in the GUI using the font dialog.

But when I change the font family for an individual object through the font dialog subscript and size formatting for parts of the text is
lost.

[image]

If I want to change the font family in the above svg file, I lose the bold for `Friends`

How can I just change the font family without losing other font features?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Extensions > Text > Replace font*

It's a little quirky, but anyway it does work

You need to spell the fonts exactly and include any spaces, and the font names need to be enclosed within single quote marks.

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: Pity I didn't spell formatting correctly . . .LOL

Comment: Content and style should be kept separated. At least you applied italics correctly. 

Comment: @Wolff, ideally yes, but Inkscape has no text "styles" in the GUI, as far as I know, although you can kind of wangle CSS styles by using the 'Merge Styles into CSS' Extension.

Comment: I see, but I just tried to be funny. I meant this question is about *formatting*, not *spelling*, so you're good. 

Comment: @Wolff - sorry, I was still in full explanation mode . . . 